# How to prevent click event on a active class inside another click event with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have several items which has been gotten `.active` class by clicking on them. Now, I need no click events will happened at any `.active` class. I have many click functions which makes the item `active`. So, for preventing click on the active classes, I wrote the prevent function at another place and call them inside every click functions. But, it didn't work.

```
$('body').on('click', '#one', function() {  
   $(this).addClass('active');
   // do something more
    noClickOnActive();
});
$('body').on('click', '#two', function() {  
   $(this).addClass('active');
   // do something more
    noClickOnActive();
}); 

function noClickOnActive() {
    $('body').on('click', '.content.active', function(event) {  
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation();
    }); 
};
```

How to make it working?

[Fiddle work](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/v99g73zs/1/)

Comment: Are you saying that once the element has the active class added to it, the original click event should be removed?

Comment: Yes, should be removed from the active class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use below code . with jquery [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) function you can check if element has class or not. it return true/false .

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v99g73zs/2/)

```
 $('body').on('click', '#one', function() {  
   if($(this).hasClass('active')){
      return false;
   }
   $(this).addClass('active');
    alert('clicked');
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

Event handlers work in the order they are registered. So you may need to put this prevent default event on `active` class at the top of all other click events.

```
$('body').on('click', '.content.active', function(event) {  
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation();
}); 

//Other event handlers code must be below
```

Else bind the event to `.content` and check for class there

```js
 $('body').on('click', '.content', function(event) {  
if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation();
 } else {
     $(this).addClass("active");
 }
});
```

```css
.content {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid yellow;
margin-right: 10px;
padding: 5px;
}
.content:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
.content.active {
background: yellow;
cursor: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="content" id="one">
<p>Click Me</p>
</div>
<div class="content" id="two">
<p>Another Click Me</p>
</div>
```

Comment: event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation(); can be replaced with return false if they are used together.

Answer (score 1):

If clicking is the issue, that means it has some action tied to it. Would removing the action from the element solve the problem? Like on click, set link's href to "".

Or simply put an if statement in your inputs and links. If you don't have a lot, it shouldn't be a hard task.